# Can it be possible to fetch parts of audio file and load in AudioBufferSourceNode?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to optimize the loading times of audio files in a project where we need to use [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode). It requires audio buffer to be loaded..
but can it be possible that i can load say first 10 mins of audio first, and play it while download other part in background. And later create another source node which loads with second part of audio file.

My current implementation loads all of the audio first. Which isn't great as it takes time. My files are 60-70 MB long.

```js
function getData() {
  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'viper.ogg', true);

  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  request.onload = function() {
    var audioData = request.response;

    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        source.buffer = buffer;

        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.loop = true;
      },

      function(e){ console.log("Error with decoding audio data" + e.err); });

  }

  request.send();
}
```

Comment: You can let browser manage this for you via HTML5 [Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio). It is async and it has buffering capability. Then you should find Partial content (206) responses in your Network tab (must be supported by backend aswell)

Comment: See [Media Source API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API), formally known as Media Source Extensions (MSE).

Comment: these ain't going to work. i would need the partial content in AudioBufferSource because of precise accuracy requirement. any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want by using the [WebCodecs API](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/) (which is currently only available in Chrome) but it requires some plumbing.

To get the file as a stream you could use `fetch()` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

Then you would need to demux the encoded file to get the raw audio data to decode it with an [`AudioDecoder`](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/#audiodecoder-interface). With a bit of luck it will output [`AudioData`](https://w3c.github.io/webcodecs/#audiodata) objects. These objects can be used to get the raw sample data which can then be used to create an `AudioBuffer`.

There are not many WebCodecs examples available yet. I think the [example which shows how to decode an MP4](https://github.com/w3c/webcodecs/tree/main/samples/mp4-decode) is the most similar to your use case available so far.